# Load event not working as expected when extracting image dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a slider with 100 images and I want to extract the `height` of each of them so I use an inline `onload` event like this (`src` is dynamically handled by a template engine, server side and there's no problem there):

```
<img src="<%=i.imgPath%>" style="width: 100%; max-height: 100%" onload="
   var maxHeight = $(this).height();
   console.log(maxHeight)">
```

The strange thing is that only about half of the images log the right `height` and if I wrap the javascript inside a `setTimeout` function then I can see that the more time I use the more images log the correct `height` until a time where all images log the correct height.
So I know that this has to do with the timing of the `load` event, but shouldn't it fire only after the image has finished loading and thus everything was there?
So:
1) Why is this happening?
2) Hos to make it work?

Comment: Does not appear that `<img>` `height` is being checked, but one of `<img>` parent elements `height` is being checked?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question. I was extracting both heights but the problem is the same with just the image itself. I also changed to jQuery to simplify as the problem is the same.

Comment: How does jQuery simplify the `javascript`? Is jQuery defined when the images are loaded at `html`?

Comment: Yes it is defined and jQuery simplifies because native javascript looks more unfamiliar/complex: `this.getBoundingClientRect().height`

Comment: Have you tried `javascript` at stacksnippets at Answer? You can get the `height` of an `<img>` at `load` event using `this.naturalHeight`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`javascript` at Question does not check `<img>` `height`, but rather a gets the `.height` property of `.getBoundingClientRect()` from one of the `<img>` parent elements

```
$(this).parents('.outWrap')[0].getBoundingClientRect()
```

Substitute `this.naturalHeight` for `.getBoundingClientRect().height`

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/55/55" 
     style="width: 100%; max-height: 100%" 
     onload=" var maxHeight = this.naturalHeight; console.log(maxHeight)">
```

Comment: It works! But I'm still confused WHY is this happening. Shouldn't on `onload` the image `.height` property be defined?

Comment: Where is the `height` set at the `<img>` element at `html` at Question? _`HTMLImageElement.height`
Is a unsigned long that reflects the [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-height) HTML attribute, indicating the rendered height of the image in CSS pixels._ ,  _"`HTMLImageElement.naturalHeight` Read only
Returns a unsigned long representing the intrinsic height of the image in CSS pixels, if it is available; else, it shows 0."_ [HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement)

Comment: It only has `max-height: 100%` applied.